# Understanding call x"91"

Tags: cobol

Can someone please help me understand call x"91" function 11 and function 12 with simple example. I have tried to search and couldn't understand it. Right now I an using this code in COBOL under UNIX environment,Does this call works in windows environment as well?

Comment: Googled `"cobol" "x91" "function 11"`... holy crap! talk about a lack of search results. It would appear that `x91` functions are just a place vendors put their miscellaneous 'external system' routines. Code some code we could look at?

Comment: The documentation at http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.enterprisedeveloper.eclipsewin%2FHRCLRHCALL6E.html is the only obvious mention. But it's completely unhelpful :-/

Comment: aha! better escape-fu helps! Googling `"cobol" "x\"91\"" "function 11"` gives... `function 11` *sets* the *programmable* COBOL switches, and `function 12` *reads* them back.

Comment: http://www.cobug.com/cobug/forums/cobolLang/177.shtml is an example of calling `function 35`, in MS DOS fwiw (so that should indicate that it will work on windows). For 11 & 12, presumably by 'switches' they mean the command-line arguments that were passed to the cobol executable.

Comment: Which COBOL compiler are you using? Why do you want to know if it will work under Windows?

Comment: migrating a COBOL code from UNIX to windows platform and this particular call is used in that COBOL code. Microfocus COBOL

Comment: This looks like this is a Microfocus invention. See this [example](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.microfocus.eclipse.help.windows%2Fhtml%2Frhrtsw02.htm). The functions you are asking about are used to set the switches on/off from within the program as opposed to from the command line when starting the program. Notice this example is from a document for Windows, so I would presume these calls would be supported. Ive never seen or used them before :-)

Answer (score 2):

http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/#what-are-the-xf4-xf5-and-x91-routines

The CALL's X"F4", X"F5", X"91" are from MF.
You can find them in the online MF doc under
Library Routines.

F4/F5 are for packing/unpacking bits from/to bytes.
91 is a multi-use call. Implemented are the subfunctions
get/set cobol switches (11, 12) and get number of call params (16).

Use

```
CALL X"F4" USING
           BYTE-VAR
           ARRAY-VAR
       RETURNING STATUS-VAR
```

to pack the last bit of each byte in the 8 byte ARRAY-VAR into corresponding bits of the 1 byte BYTE-VAR.

The X”F5” routine takes the eight bits of byte and moves them to the corresponding occurrence within array.

X”91” is a multi-function routine.

```
CALL X"91" USING
           RESULT-VAR
           FUNCTION-NUM
           PARAMETER-VAR
       RETURNING STATUS-VAR
```

As mentioned by Roger, OpenCOBOL supports FUNCTION-NUM of 11, 12 and 16.

11 and 12 get and set the on off status of the 8 (eight) run-time OpenCOBOL switches definable in the SPECIAL-NAMES paragraph. 16 returns the number of call parameters given to the current module.

Answer (score 1):

`x'91'` is a general library routine, for a complete list of those see the [MF documentation](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/visual-cobol/VC22/EclWin/HRCLRHCALL17.html).
This documentation also specifies what its [function 11](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/visual-cobol/VC22/EclWin/HRCLRHCALL6E.html) and [function 12](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/visual-cobol/VC22/EclWin/HRCLRHCALL6F.html) do: they set/read the [COBOL runtime switches](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/visual-cobol/VC22/EclWin/HRRTRHRTSW01.html) [0-7](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/visual-cobol/VC22/EclWin/HRRTRHRTSW06.html) and the internal debugging mode switch.

Other than these library routines you can also [read them one by one](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/visual-cobol/VC22/EclWin/) from COBOL and set "some" switches via the [`SET` statement](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/visual-cobol/VC22/EclWin/HRLHLHPDFC03.html).